# R - map a list to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of elements that I want to find mapped elements based on a data frame.

Input:

`n = c(3, 2, 5)`

```
a = c(2, 3, 5)
b = c("a", "b", "c")
df = data.frame(a, b)
```

How to return a list of mapped elements `c("b", "a", "c")` based on data frame `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` :

```
df$b[match(df$a,n)]
# [1] "b" "a" "c" # if you specified stringsAsFactors=FALSE in df creation
```

If you didn't specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in df creation the output would be

```
[1] b a c
Levels: a b c
```

Explanation of the answer : `match` will give the index of the `a` column of the numbers who "match" (ie, are equal to) `n`. You then just have to select the elements of column `b` in that specified order.